# Opening web link using only java (console)

Tags: java, web, console

Is there an option how to open a link using only console so for instance, If I enter 1 it will open a separate window where it will open my web link? I mean I want to use external links (URLs) where when I press 1 a chrome window will open with my URL. Is that possible and if so how, because I have only seen people do it using Java Swing. Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I tried and this worked:

```
try {
  Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
  URI oURL = new URI("http://www.google.com");
  desktop.browse(oURL);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will also need to implement URI and java.awt library

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough to me, but what I understood is that you want to open the website link from the browser console, if that's what you mean you can do it using this javascript code

**For external URLs :**

`window.location = 'http (s): // www.example.com'`

**and for the internal URLs :**

__ `window.location = '/ file.php'` 
or `window.location = '/ file.html'` 
or `window.location = '/ your_route'`

Comment: I need external for URLs

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your description you want to open a web link based on an input (1 in your case) in your Java console app. You can use the method exec as the follownig:

```
 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer https://www.google.com");    
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here the exec method calls a command which here I call Google Chrome to open Google.com.
Using this in Windows will open the default browser showing the website.

Comment: it doesent work only displays error : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chrome": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: i have updated the answer to use explorer instead of chrome.